# how to find dynamically category which in array model

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, nosql

how to find the record from category in array in a model,

I have a model which has an a type data Array and I want to search it by  request body ,

example that I have

article which has category in array

article model  = `{ category : ['fiction', 'action', 'politic']}`

so if the request only want `['fiction' , 'action']` only, how to put it in mongoose find() ??

I hope my question make sense thanks

Comment: Try with $in  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#in

Comment: db.collection.find( { article: { $in: ['fiction' , 'action' ] } } )

Comment: db.collection.find( { article: { $in: req.body.articalArray } } )
Here req.body.articalArray  is ['fiction' , 'action' ]

Comment: I will try it soon and let you know, thanks for answered